# How to Authorize the service object for a specific user

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs, google-docs-api

In google docs api Developer's guide at many places it says 
      // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user
Can any one please tell how to do that exactly..
especailly in my case where for authentication I'm sending a POST request to https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin and then parsing Authentication token.

Comment: Figured it out

service.SetAuthenticationToken("AuthToken");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to have the library perform ClientLogin for you:

```
service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
```

For more details, check https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests_with_clientlogin